# Problem with Unity after installing Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, launcher, plugins

I have installed Chrome Remote Desktop utility, but I don't know if I have configured the chrome.desktop file correctly.

When Ubuntu starts, unity panel and top bar don't appear, and I need to do a `compiz --replace` to restart compiz. The following messages appears:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: commands
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: commands
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/pablo/.compiz/session/10b09b2d4528c86a2c14547138921521300000016930007"
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2016-02-06 00:12:10 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:216 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 xim.controller XIMController.cpp:103 IBus natively supported.
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 unityct(io) <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-02-06 00:12:10 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: showdesktop
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: showdesktop
ERROR 2016-02-06 00:12:13 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2016-02-06 00:12:13 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Update:

I have news about the problem. I found that if I disable automatic login in my personal account, setting the option menu in which I can choose the guest account or the personal account, then Unity starts normally. On the other hand, setting automatic login leads to an irregular boot of unity panel.

Some hints?